# Post request in PHP to form

Tags: php, forms, http, post

I'm trying to send a POST request to a site which has a form that directs to a tcl script.
I can see in the source of the page -

```
<FORM method=post action=<script>.tcl name=form1
```

I tried writing a php script that sends the request

```
$url = '<url>/<script>.tcl';
$data = array('Username' => ... , 'Password' => ...);
$options = array('http' => array('method'  => 'POST','content' => http_build_query($data)));
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
```

But I receive: file_get_contents(..) -  failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error

Im new at this so I would appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to use cURL.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it and now I get - The requested URL cannot be accessed due to a system error on this server.

Comment: Is your URL some kind of protected by something, like htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a job for [cURL](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

For example:

```
<?php

$url = '<url>/<script>.tcl';
$data = array('Username' => ... , 'Password' => ...);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

// Return the response...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

echo $response;
```

Comment: I get the same result - The requested URL cannot be accessed due to a system error on this server.

Comment: Does your server have curl installed? `in_array('curl', get_loaded_extensions())` and are you sure the url is correct?